# Cannot add AD-groups to sites in SP 2016

Tags: 2016

I am able to add users with no problems, but cannot find any security groups. 
I noticed in user profile sync service, I can only select users. In SP 2013 I could select whether to synchronize users and groups or only users. 
Any advice on this? 
[image: This is from my SP2013 environment (Configure Synchronization Settings), in SP2016 i have no options here]

Comment: What do you mean by "find", and where are you adding the users? When granting permissions to a site, if you just type in the name of the AD group, does the group resolve? (It should.)

Comment: Yes, it should, but it doesn't. This was working fine in my SP2013 environment, but does not work in SP2016.  @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP The group does not resolve.

Comment: Are you using adimport or mim for user profile sync?

Comment: I think you mix up two things here: PeoplePicker for granting permissions and UserProfile Synchronization. PeoplePicker does not need a user or group to be at UPS to grant permissions. What are you trying to achieve? Get those groups in UPS or granting them permissions on sites via PeoplePicker?

Comment: I want to add AD-groups to sites permissions. I thought I could not find them with the peoplepicker because the UPS did not work properly. I would be glad if that is not the case. I hate messing with UPS ;)

Comment: Thanks for clarification.. We need more infos for troubleshooting. Do you get an error on the page when searching for a group? PeoplePicker-Errors are also logged in ULSLog. Please have a look there.

Comment: I don't get an error on the frontend (peoplepicker), have not checked the ULSLog, but will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check the credential of account which u using to sync AD, does it have the replicate AD objects permission on AD.
this article is rather old but the essence remains the same:
http://www.jppinto.com/2011/04/configure-active-directory-ad-synchronization-for-sharepoint-2010/